# pass local variable to the callee as a member of a vector

Tags: c++

I have this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class B
{
    public:
    std::string s;

    B()
    {
        std::cout<<"constructing B"<<std::endl;
    }    
    ~B()
    {
        std::cout<<"destroying B"<<std::endl;
    }
};
class A
{
    private:
    void Do(std::vector<B>& v)
    {
        B b;
        b.s = "this is a test";
        v.push_back(b);
    }

    public:
    void Check()
    {
        std::vector<B> v;
        Do(v);
        std::cout<<v[0].s<<std::endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    A a;
    a.Check();
}
```

Question: this worked, so apparently compiler knew that `b` should not go out of scope, but is this a good way to populate vector `v` with objects created inside `Do`?
The output of the above is

```
constructing B
destroying B
this is a test
destroying B
```

Is this correct to assume that `b` was copied, then older value was destroyed and newer passed in vector?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back - don't assume, check the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector stores a copy of local object b. So there is no problem with the code relative to this local variable

Answer (score 1):

`push_back` copied `b` into a new element created for `v`, then `b` was destroyed before `Do` returned.